# Line break in address part of moderncv

Tags: line-breaking, titles, moderncv

I used `\address{}{}` command in `banking` style of class `moderncv`, and because my address is long, `moderncv` does not break the line automatically. I also tried the `\newline` command but it did not work for me. Please help me in this problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a permanent solution, because building the title in `banking` style is a little bit complicated. Usually the street and number is placed in only one separate line (without be able to have line breaks!), then follows in the next line postcode city and country, divided with `~~--~~`.

With the following workaround you can simulate the original behaviour (but see, that you have to find out were it is best to break the line):

```
\address{street and number very long very long very long very long 
         very long very long}{very long very long very long very long~--~postcode city}{country}
```

The first line with the street and number ends after the 6th `very long`, then I added the missing parts in front of `postcode`. To simulate the dividing between `city` and `country` I added before the postcode `~--~`.

The complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy; head 3, body 3
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number very long very long very long very long 
         very long very long}{very long very long very long very long~--~postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list 
  before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

gives you now:

[image: resulting title]

Answer (score 0):

Try creating newlines using `\\`, e.g.

```
\address{Line1\\Line2\\Line3\\}{zipcode city}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Does not work in banking style!!

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation, except that I just wanted to add some info before the address, without too much trouble. So I modified a bit chrisma's solution, and replaced the `\address` in his example by this:

```
\address{\hspace{3cm}Extra bit of info \hspace{3cm}}{Street and number~--~postcode city}{country}
```

And here's what I got:

[image]